# Converting obj-c code to swift 2 block issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have the following code, in objective C.

```
[pixelData processPixelsWithBlock:^(JGPixel *pixel, int x, int y) {

}];
```

now, to me, the swift equivalent would be

```
pixelData.processPixelsWithBlock({(pixel: JGPixel, x: Int, y: Int) -> Void in

})
```

however, that is throwing an error of

Cannot convert value of type '(JGPixel, Int, Int) -> Void' to expected argument type '((UnsafeMutablePointer, Int32, Int32) -> Void)!'

Can anyone help explain where i'm going wrong, and how I can learn more about this error. Thanks!

Comment: Is JGPixel a class or a structure in Obj-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `withUnsafeMutablePointer` function as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:FSs24withUnsafeMutablePointeru0_rFzTRq_FzGVSs20UnsafeMutablePointerq__q0__q0_). Something along the lines of:

```
var pixel: JGPixel = // whatever
withUnsafeMutablePointer(&pixel, { (ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<JGPixel>) -> Void in
    pixelData.processPixelsWithBlock({(ptr, x: Int, y: Int) -> Void in

    })
})
```

EDIT: Just realised I forgot to pass ptr to the function properly. Fixed above.

Comment: Hi. This seems to be on the right track, but now it throws the error  'Variable used within its own initial value' - i understand that it is complaining, because i am using the &pixel, in the same line that i'm declaring it - how do i get around this? Thanks!